# Clicking button not fetching value from DB in VB.net

Tags: .net, database, vb.net, combobox

I have checked with MsgBox also, my value is changing from combobox but I only get first record as total amount always e.g. If i Select thinkpad from combobx then it will show me 16,000 USD but when try to change thinkpad to yogapad from combox it works fine as I get number 2 as value of combobox but I see no chang ein 16,000 USD. here is my code

```
Public Class Total_Amount_Report

    Private Sub Total_Amount_Report_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        sql = "SELECT *  FROM pt_funds"



        Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)
        da.Fill(ds, "TotalAmounts")
        ComboBox1.DataSource = ds.Tables("TotalAmounts")
        ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "Project Name"
        ComboBox1.ValueMember = "ID"



    End Sub



    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim sql2 As String
        sql2 = "SELECT * FROM pt_funds WHERE ID=" & ComboBox1.SelectedValue & " "
        MsgBox(ComboBox1.SelectedValue, MsgBoxStyle.Information, "kjhuu")
        Dim da1 As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql2, con)
        da1.Fill(ds, "ProjectAmount")
        Label3.Text = ds.Tables("ProjectAmount").Rows(0).Item("Total Amount")

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Use parameters to avoid sql injection and avoid exceptions.

Comment: set a breakpoint an make sure `ComboBox1.SelectedValue` is what you think it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DataAdapter.Fill` creates a new table if it doesn't exist, but if it does, it only updates it adding the results of the command.

So, if you select thinkpad on you combobox and click the button, the `ProjectAmount` table looks like this:

```
ID      Total Amount
1       16000
```

When you change to yogapad and click the button, the table now looks like this:

```
ID      Total Amount
1       16000
2       30000
```

Now, here

```
Label3.Text = ds.Tables("ProjectAmount").Rows(0).Item("Total Amount")
```

you're **always** selecting the first row, wich is ID 1, Total Amount 16000.

Either do a `ds.Tables("ProjectAmount").Clear` or use a new `DataSet` everytime you click the button.